# Interfacing with Spring boot Database using Heroku custom domain

Tags: json, angularjs, spring-boot, heroku

Currently in the ending stages of trying to get my app online.  However using the custom domain, which is on a standard goDaddy Account, I cant view any of my tables

```
$http.get("https://HEROKU DOMAIN/chat").then(function (response){

    $scope.chats = response.data;


  });
$scope.postchat = function(chatMsg){
    var data = {

      chatMsg: chatMsg
    };


    $http.post("https://HEROKU DOMAIN/chat", JSON.stringify(data))
    location.reload();
  };
});
```

This is the AngularJs code . I've tried getting and posting from the Heroku domain, the custom domain and the dns target with no avail.  Everything works on my Heroku domain, but on the custom domain no data shows up, and I cant post any data.  Here is the front end html code if anyone is interested

```
<div class="div1">

    <table class="table table2">
        <tr><th>Messages</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="chat in chats">
            <td>{{chat.chatMsg}}</td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    Chat <input ng-model="chatMsg"/>

    <button class="button button2" ng-click="postchat(chatMsg)">Send</button>
</div>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, there might be some security that my custom domain has in regards to who can post and who can get from it.  However, as I understand it my custom domain is merely pointing to my heroku app.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if you use http instead of https while using the custom domain everything works.

```
$http.get("http://CUSTOM DOMAIN/chat").then(function (response){

    $scope.chats = response.data;


  });
$scope.postchat = function(chatMsg){
    var data = {

      chatMsg: chatMsg
    };


    $http.post("http://CUSTOM DOMAIN/chat", JSON.stringify(data))
    location.reload();
  };
});
```